# Rewriting into a file

Tags: java, file, file-io, url-rewriting

I write a simple function like this:

```
private static void write(String Swrite) throws IOException {
   if(!file.exists()) {
      file.createNewFile();
   }
   FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file);
   if(Swrite!=null)
      fop.write(Swrite.getBytes());
   fop.flush();
   fop.close();
}
```

Every time I call it, it rewrite and then I just get the last items that are written. How can I change it to not rewriting? The `file` variable is defined globally as a `File`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your `FileOutputStream` [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), you need to add the `boolean append` parameter. It will then look like this:

```
FileOutputStream fop = new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

This tells `FileOutputStream` that it should append the file instead of clearing and rewriting all of its current data.

Comment: but still a little problem, it doesnt make any space, it writes exactly after last character so it will not be readable, how can i make it to give an space after each writing?

Comment: chang `fop.write(...)` to `fop.write(...+"\n")`

Comment: it didnt work. it said no suitale constructor of that kind for write(). although i managed to solve it out, but there is another miner question, is there anyway to write in a file each time in next line? i mean first write in first line, then second line and so on from the beginning of the line.

Comment: i found that the ascii code for it is 10, but because its character and my function is writing strings, so its not going to work. any other idea?

Answer (score 2):

Use constrctor which takes *append* flag as parameter.

```
FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

Comment: but still a little problem, it doesnt make any space, it writes exactly after last character so it will not be readable, how can i make it to give an space after each writing

Comment: @MostafaAlli: then **write** space

Answer (score 1):

you should open the file in `append`  mode for this, by default `FileOutputStream` opens file in `write` mode. And you need not check for existence of `file`, it will be done implicitly by `FileOutputStream`

```
private static void write(String Swrite) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file, true);
   if(Swrite!=null)
      fop.write(Swrite.getBytes());
   fop.flush();
   fop.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) if your trying to write at certain byte offsets.

Comment: Its not necessarily a certain offset, he just wants the file appended.

Answer (score 0):

Tow parameter constructor is right. And it is redundant:

```
if(!file.exists()) {
      file.createNewFile();
}
```

Constructor will do it for you.